# Re-use the view output matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

In Matlab, I create a fairly complicated 3D plot, then manipulate the view option by hand up to a point where I am happy with what I see (below). How can I reuse the parameters of the final view? I can get the output of the `view` command which is a 4 by 4 matrix, but the latter does not seem to be reusable?

[image]

Comment: One trick to use if you have done a lot of things in the figure window is to use the "Generate Code" function from the File menu in the figure window. Then look through the code for the section that does whatever you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, based on Suever's comments, I realized that all the figure properties I need can be accessed through the Graphical Interface called `matlab.graphics.axis.Axes`. This is where the parameters of the camera can be found. Another approach is to find them one by one as follows:

```
get(gca,'Projection')
get(gca,'CameraPosition')
get(gca,'CameraViewAngle')
get(gca,'CameraTarget')
```

and then set them directly in the script:

```
set(gca,'Projection','perspective')
set(gca,'CameraPosition',[-7 -5 3]/15)
set(gca,'CameraViewAngle',85)
set(gca,'CameraTarget',[0 .5 0])
```

I originally thought the `view` command would provide this information at once.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get something out of `view` that you can then pass to `view` to reconstruct the viewpoint, you need to specify [*two* outputs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/view.html) to `view` which will yield the current azimuth and elevation.

```
[az, el] = view(ax1);
```

You can then pass these to `view` on a different (or the same) axes to specify the viewpoint

```
view(ax2, az, el);
```

You can also use the [`View` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_view) of the `axes` object.

```
AzEl = get(ax1, 'View');
set(ax2, 'View', AzEl);
```

Note, however, that there are many properties which control the view of an axes including the `Projection`, the `DataAspectRatio`, the `PlotBoxAspectRatio` and all of the [camera properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#zmw57dd0e55440). Depending on your use case, you may need to specify these as well.

Comment: Interesting (this is mentioned in the help) but by doing so, the parameters of the camera view are lost like campos. I would like to know whether it is possible to retrieve all the active parameters of a given view.