# Copying axes position and camera properties

Tags: matlab, rendering, matlab-figure, surface, point-clouds

I have a point cloud and a tracks of cells which I display using following commands:

```
showPointCloud(RawCoors,repmat(PointValues([1,3]));
hold on
for jj=1:5
    %... calculate x,y,z for each one of 5 tracks
    surface([x;x],[y;y],[z;z],[Colors(1:ii);Colors(1:ii)],'facecol','no','edgecol','interp','linew',5,'EdgeAlpha',1);  
end
```

This results in a subpar rendering:

[image: showpointcloud(...) hold on surface(...)]

As a quick workaround I would like to display the point cloud and overlay the tracks. For this I need to get all camera position and zoom properties form the point cloud:

[image: just showpointcloud(...)]

and apply that to the tracks:

[image: just surface(...)]

However I have not been able to set a correct combination of [these parameters](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html) and `view()` like this

```
C=ax1.CameraPosition;
ax2.CameraPosition=C;
```

to get the correct view of the tracks.

Is there a way to copy all of the axes properties in order to get right sized tracks?

Do you have a better way to solve this rendering problem?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36782582/re-use-the-view-output-matrix-in-matlab/36782953#36782953) may be relevant

Comment: Thank you, the combination of the parameters in both answers was enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combination of the following parameters from @Suever's comment plus `view()` solved the problem:

```
C=Ax1.Projection;Ax2.Projection=C;
C=Ax1.CameraTarget;Ax2.CameraTarget=C;
C=Ax1.CameraPosition;Ax2.CameraPosition=C;
C=Ax1.CameraViewAngle;Ax2.CameraViewAngle=C;
C=Ax1.DataAspectRatio;Ax2.DataAspectRatio=C;
C=Ax1.PlotBoxAspectRatio;Ax2.PlotBoxAspectRatio=C;
```